# loop multiple lists if exist and check for match (Python)

Tags: python

What would be the best way to loop multiple lists if exist, then check each element in each list for a match and non match, then create a list for matching and non matching elements corresponding to that list.

I currently have a for loop for only 'ing1',  but is there a more practical way to achieve this?

```
        ing1 = request.POST.getlist('ingredients1')
        ing2 = request.POST.getlist('ingredients2')
        ing3 = request.POST.getlist('ingredients3')


        for ele in ing1[1:]:
            ele_split = ele.split(",")
            for ele2 in ele_split:
                ing1list.append(ele2.strip().lower())
        print(ing1list)
```

Comment: Seems like you need `set()` data structure and its method `intersection()`

Comment: Well, I see no matching attempt anywhere in the question. The first element of every list is ignored, the rest is split on comma, and those split elements appended as lower case stripped strings to a new list (not even declared in the code). Please amend otherwise the question is IMO too open ended and may not be a good fit to attract helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

try creating a list that contains

`lst_of_entries = [ing1, ing2, ing3]`

then performing what you currently are on ing1 to all the elements in the list by iterating through it. This will also require you to create another list of output variable names so that you can append them.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO, can you write in code exactly what you write in plain text?. Please read this guideline: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer